# PHPUnit mock method in another class

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I started to use PHPUnit to test and mock methods in php. If the methods are in the same class, there isn't a problem.
But I didn't understood yet how to mock a method, which is in another class.

```php
class classA {
  public function funcA() {
    $classB = new classB();
    $value = $classB->getValue();
    return $value;
  }
}
```

```php
class classB {
  public function getValue() {
    return "this is my value";
  }
}
```

If getValue would be in classA, I could do the following:

```php
class testClassA {
  function testFuncA() {
    $mb = $this
      ->getMockBuilder(classA::class)
      ->setMethods(array('getValue'))
      ->getMock();
    $mb
      ->method('getValue')
      ->will($this->returnValue('my new value');
    $value = $mb->funcA();

    $this->assertEquals('my new value', $value);
  }
}
```

But how can I do it in the case, we have above?

**Edit:**
[Jon Stirling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/934966/jon-stirling) asked to instantiate classB in the constructer instead of the tested method
So let's edit classA

```php
class classA {

  $private classB;

  public function __construct(){
    $this->classB = new classB();
  }

  public function funcA() {
    $value = $this->classB->getValue();
    return $value
  }
}
```

So how is it possible in that way?

Comment: Ideally you would inject an instance of classB into classA (via constructor, setter, or as a method arg of funcA), but since you instantiate classB inside the method you want to test, you've made it difficult (I suppose you could manipulate an autoloader) to mock.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I edited the post now. Do you have any ideas, how I should go on now?

Comment: That's not what I said at all. I said it should be _injected into_ the object. All you've done is move where you instantiate it in the same class.

Comment: Okay I misunderstood that.. But I think it will not be possible in my scenario..

Comment: Your `testFuncA` test doesn't actually test anything. It mocks out a method and tests the mocked-out method returns the fake data. It doesn't actually run any of your code.

Answer (score 0):

In lieu of actually decoupling your classes such that the test can inject a `classB` object at test time, the answer is to use reflection to replace class members:

```
class classA {

    private $classB;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->classB = new classB();
    }

    public function funcA() {
        $value = $this->classB->getValue();
        return $value
    }
}


class testClassA {
    function testFuncA() {
        $mb = $this
            ->getMockBuilder(classB::class)
            ->setMethods(array('getValue'))
            ->getMock();

        $mb
            // XXX must be called EXACTLY once
            ->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getValue')
            ->will($this->returnValue('my new value');

        $ma = $this
            ->getMockBuilder(classA::class)
            ->setMethods([
                // XXX do not mock any methods except the constructor!
            ])
            // XXX avoid any side effects from classA's constructor:
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        // XXX inject the mock B into the mock A
        $reflector = new ReflectionClass($ma);
        $prop = $reflector->getProperty('classB');
        $prop->setAccessible(true);
        $prop->setValue($ma, $mb);

        $value = $ma->funcA();

        $this->assertEquals('my new value', $value);
    }
}
```

The `->expects()` operator counts as an assertion. All this test tests is that `classA` calls the `getValue` method on its `$classB` member. Not too useful, IMO.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to do it in that way, but when I try to execute the test, I got  the exception  


`ReflectionException : Property classB does not exist`  


I know, that the whole test is not useful right now, but I am using it in a different scenario and there it makes sense, I think :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this one example:

```
$returnValue = 'my new value';
$this->app->bind(classB::class,
    function () use
    (
        $returnValue
    ) : MockObject
    {
        $mock = $this->getMockBuilder(classB::class)
            ->setConstructorArgs(['config' => uniqid()])//If need can set constructor values.
            ->onlyMethods([//List of method that return will be changed.
                'getValue',
            ])
            ->getMock();
        //Set for method return value.
        $mock->method('getValue')
            ->willReturn($returnValue);

        return $mock;
    });
```